# Can't print false when integer is NULL, C++

Tags: c++, null, integer

I wrote the code below. The code reads 2 txt files(contain numbers) and stores these numbers in a 3rd array from minimum to maximum.

After than the user is able to enter a random integer number. The programm seach the last array(binary search algorith) if that number exists. If exists, it prints TRUE otherwise it prints FALSE.

My problem is that my code dont print FAlSE. Any suggestion?
Thank you for your time in advance and sorry for my english and any other mistakes... I'm new here! :P

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_search(int merarray[], int p, int inim, int imax) {
    int imid = (inim + imax) / 2;

    if(merarray[imid] > p) {
        binary_search(merarray, p, inim, imid - 1);
    } else if(merarray[imid] < p) {
        binary_search(merarray, p, imid + 1, imax);
    } else {
        return imid;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arrayA[100];
    int arrayB[100];
    int mergedarray[200];
    int i, j, h;

    ifstream inputFile1("arrayA.txt");

    if(inputFile1.good()) {
        int current_number = 0;
        i = 0;
        while(inputFile1 >> current_number) arrayA[i++] = current_number;

        inputFile1.close();
    }

    ifstream inputFile2("arrayB.txt");

    if(inputFile2.good()) {
        int current_number = 0;
        i = 0;
        while(inputFile2 >> current_number) arrayB[i++] = current_number;

        inputFile2.close();
    }

    i = 0, j = 0, h = 0;
    while(i != 100 || j != 100) {
        if(arrayA[i] <= arrayB[j]) {
            mergedarray[h] = arrayA[i];
            i = i + 1;
            h = h + 1;
        } else {
            mergedarray[h] = arrayB[j];
            j = j + 1;
            h += 1;
            ;
        }
    }

    ofstream outputfile;
    outputfile.open("mergedarray.txt");
    for(int count = 0; count < h; count++) {
        outputfile << mergedarray[count] << " ";
    }

    outputfile.close();

    int p;
    cout << "Please, enter an integer: ";
    cin >> p;
    int mini = 0;
    int maxi = sizeof(mergedarray);
    int result = binary_search(mergedarray, p, mini, maxi);

    if(result = p) {
        cout << "TRUE";
    } else {
        cout << "FALSE";
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(result = p)` assigns `p` to `result` and checks if `result` is now non-zero. You probably  meant `if(result == p)` to compare them.

Comment: By the way C++20 adds `std::midpoint`. Building a mid point function is surprisingly difficult due to overflow &c. `(inim+imax)/2` is way down the list.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: you can make use of your compiler to catch such mistakes, just turn on warnings and read them: https://godbolt.org/z/vMzrdx

Comment: you also miss to return from `binary_search` on most branches. Such mistakes are common, I make them on a regular basis, but a compiler will catch them for me

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but notice that the code that reads into the first array and the code that reads into the second array are almost identical. This cries out to be moved into a function, so that you only have to write the code that reads a file once; you can call that function twice, once for each array.